# How Kafka detects unclean leader election?

Tags: apache-kafka

After leader replica fails, and a new leader replica is elected, how Kafka knows if the new leader is clean (was in-sync when the previous leader failed)?

For example say there are replicas 1, 2 and 3, where 1 is the leader. Say replica 3 goes down, then messages get written to 1 (and 2), then 1 and 2 go down. Now replica 3 comes up, and it is not clean, because it does't contain the messages written while it was down. How can Kafka detect, when 3 comes up, if it is clean or not? The leader could store the latest offset for each received message in Zookeper (or the equivalent in the latest Kafka) but would that be very inefficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `unclean.leader.election.enable` is set to `true` in Kafka, it means that Kafka allows an out-of-sync replica to become the leader during a leader election if there are no in-sync replicas available. This is considered an "unclean" leader election because the selected leader might not have all the messages that were written while it was down.

In the scenario you described:

1. **Replica 3 goes down.**
2. **Messages get written to 1 (and 2).**
3. **1 and 2 go down.**
4. **Replica 3 comes up.**

If `unclean.leader.election.enable` is set to `true`, and if there are no other in-sync replicas available, Kafka may elect Replica 3 as the leader even though it's not in sync with the latest messages.

To answer your question about how Kafka knows if the new leader is "clean" or not, when `unclean.leader.election.enable` is true:

- **Kafka does not explicitly check if the new leader is "clean."** The setting allows for the possibility of unclean leader elections, acknowledging that the elected leader might not be in sync with the latest messages.
- **The leader may not have all the messages written while it was down.** This is an accepted trade-off for cases where ensuring availability is prioritized over strict consistency.
- **Efficiency vs. Consistency trade-off:** Storing the latest offset for each received message in a distributed storage system like ZooKeeper for every leader replica could be resource-intensive and may introduce additional latency. Kafka's design, in this case, prioritizes availability and responsiveness.

If strict consistency is a higher priority for your use case, you might choose to keep `unclean.leader.election.enable` set to `false` (the default) to prevent unclean leader elections and ensure that a new leader must be fully caught up with the latest messages.

### Updated

When `unclean.leader.election.enable` is set to `false` , Kafka ensures that only replicas that are in sync with the leader can become the new leader during an election. This is done to maintain data consistency and avoid potential data loss.

Here's how Kafka determines whether a new leader is "clean" or not when `unclean.leader.election.enable` is set to `false`:

1. **In-Sync Replica (ISR) Set:**

   - Kafka maintains a concept called the In-Sync Replica (ISR) set for each partition. The ISR set consists of replicas that are in sync with the leader.
2. **Leader Election:**

   - When a leader election occurs, only replicas in the ISR set are eligible to become the new leader.
3. **Replica Catch-Up:**

   - Before a replica becomes the leader, it needs to catch up with the leader's log. If a replica is not in the ISR set or is lagging significantly behind the leader, it won't be eligible to become the new leader.
4. **Out-of-Sync Replica Handling:**

   - If a replica is out of sync and cannot catch up within a configured time (controlled by the `replica.lag.time.max.ms` property), it may be removed from the ISR set, preventing it from becoming the leader.
5. **ZooKeeper Information:**

   - Kafka uses ZooKeeper to maintain metadata, including information about the ISR set. ZooKeeper keeps track of which replicas are in sync with the leader.

By relying on the ISR set and ensuring that only replicas in sync are eligible for leadership, Kafka helps prevent the scenario where an out-of-sync replica becomes a leader. This mechanism contributes to maintaining data consistency and avoiding potential data loss during leader elections.

In summary, Kafka uses the ISR set, replica synchronization, and information stored in ZooKeeper to ensure that only in-sync replicas are considered for leadership when `unclean.leader.election.enable` is set to `false`.

Comment: So, when `unclean.leader.election.enable` is `false` (the default) Kafka somehow knows is the new leader is clean or not. The question is, how it knows that?

Comment: When unclean.leader.election.enable is set to false , Kafka ensures that only replicas that are in sync with the leader can become the new leader during an election. 
Kafka uses ZooKeeper to maintain metadata, including information about the ISR set. ZooKeeper keeps track of which replicas are in sync with the leader.
updated the Answer

Comment: if unclean leader election was not enabled, then clients would have to wait for a consistent in-sync replica to come back online before it can perform further reads and writes to that topic partition. This configuration therefore favours durability over availability.